# activating function only when tkinter button clicked on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, button, tkinter

I have made a function called `get_data['name'].`
This function gets a string('name' for example) and the output is an array of number.

I have made few button with tkinter that looks like this:

```
# A Button
A_Button = Button(GUI, image=A_Im, command=get_data('a_name'))
A_Button.grid(column=0, row=1)

# C Button
C_Button = Button(GUI,image=C_Im,command=get_data('c_name'))
C_Button.grid(column=0, row=2)

# D_Button
D_Button = Button(GUI, image=D_Im, command=get_data('d_name'))
D_Button.grid(column=0, row=3)
```

However, when i run the code, It executes the function get_data for every button, while i wanted it to work only when i click the specific button.

How can i make it work only at click?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with tkinter, but from the looks of it you're adding the command get_data to every button. Is that intended?

Comment: Yes, each button should call the function but with different input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the way you're assigning a value to the `Button`'s `command` argument, will first immediately *call* the `get_data` function. This is because you're writing it as a regular function call. In the end you end up assigning the return value of the actual function call to the `command` argument of the `Button`.

Instead what you need to to is to make sure you are assigning an actual *function* (or in general, any *callable* object) to the `command` argument. This makes sure it will be lazily evaluated and only invoked at the time you're actually clicking on the button.

A simple way to do this is by wrapping it in a small *lambda function* like this:

```
C_Button = Button(GUI,image=C_Im,command = lambda: get_data('c_name'))
```

Comment: It worked, thank you very much.